# Iframe clicável

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Bom estou precisando implementar uma forma de abrir uma propaganda ao usuario clicar no play de um iframe incorporado na minha pagina

ex: ao clicar para passar o video abre uma aba com determinada propaganda
porem não consigo gerar um link no botão do play ou em todo iframe

tentei fazer dessa forma porem sem sucesso!

```
<a href="link da publi"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9ByTCcGSIcw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Pra esses casos eu sugiro criar uma div que sobrepõe o iFrame e você adiciona um evento de 'click' usando javascript, dessa forma fica mais fácil de manipular.

Pra criar uma div que sobrepõe o iframe você pode usar o `position:absolute;` e `z-index: 9999;` e em seguida colocar tanto essa div quanto o iframe dentro de um outro elemento, assim ela vai tomar o espaço inteiro do player.

Fiz um código de exemplo que você pode utilizar.

```js
const propagandaDiv = document.querySelector('.propaganda');
propagandaDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.open('http://www.google.com/','_blank'); // Abre o link em uma nova janela
    propagandaDiv.style.display = 'none'; // Esconde a div da propaganda
});
```

```css
#player {
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
}
.propaganda {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: #000;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
    <div class="propaganda">Clique para abrir</div>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/13bsciE04xc" title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Provavelmente o evento de clicar não funcione aqui ao executar o snippet por algumas restrições, mas dentro de um documento HTML comum irá funcionar.
Espero que te ajude!

Comment: existe alguma forma de abrir essa aba sem dar foco nela? eu preciso que o usuário assista o vídeo primeiro e com esse código o usuário vai direto

Comment: Você pode criar um callback para só injetar o código do player quando o vídeo acabar, ou algo assim, daí vai depender muito do player de vídeo que você usar.Sugiro procurar um evento de conclusão de reprodução nesse player, daí você coloca nesse evento, o código para injetar o vídeo.